# How can I remove <br> tags and leave all other tags using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove the break tags from a string in xslt1.0. I tried using translate(s,'&ltbr>','') where s is string value but that removes the bold tags also.  Also tried a template but had no luck.
My question is how to remove the break tags only.

So the string:

```
<b>trying</b> to remove <br> tags only <br> and not <b>bold tags</b>
```

would be parsed as:

```
<b>trying</b> to remove tags only and not <b>bold tags</b>
```

Comment: XSLT can be applied only to (valid) XML, and your fragment is not valid XML because the `<br>` are not closed. You should consider some HTML parser for the job.

Comment: I'm not having a problem parsing the xml. That's not the issue.  That string is inside valid tags.  Problem is removing the tags in the returned xml which is similar to example.

Comment: XSLT is not a language to process strings - if you want to handle the HTML as a string use regular expressions, but this in general NOT RECOMENDED - better to parse the HTML and process the parsed result.

Comment: HTML parser: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=
    "br[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
    and normalize-space()=''
    ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this well-formed, valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<b>trying</b> to remove <br/> tags only <br/> and not <b>bold tags</b>
</list>
```

gives this result:

```
<list>
<b>trying</b> to remove  tags only  and not <b>bold tags</b>
</list>
```

Also refer to Dimitre's solution here:
[Removing empty tags from XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt)

Comment: is there someway to turn this into a template i can call upon to remove br tags.  The xml is coming back from Google as <br> and not <br/>.  I was hoping to do something like call template name = "remove_br" and pass xsl:value of s(which is provided example).

Comment: I don't think you can because <br> is not valid XML. Do you not have the possibility just to replace all strings <br> by nothing?

Comment: java offers replaceAll() for example

Comment: i am using asp.net.  I think i will try to replace all <br> tags in the xml using LINQ and then feed the clean xml into the xslt. I will keep you posted.

Comment: I used ASP.net to do a replace on all <br> tags using Dim clean As String = Regex.Replace(fullXML, "&lt;br&gt;", "").  I will give Peter credit for steering me in my right direction.  Thanks Peter.