# Remove empty tags in XML using Regex ABAP

Tags: regex, xml, abap, abap-st

I have a problem with generating XML. I used Simple Transformation. Many of tags in my XML are empty. I found an information that I can get rid of those tags using Regex but it doesn't work perfectly. Let me show you how it looks.

Without Regex:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Invoice 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
     <cbc:DueDate /> 
     <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode> 
     <cbc:Note /> 
     <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>PLN</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode> 
     <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode /> 
     <cbc:BuyerReference /> 
     <cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cbc:StartDate /> 
      <cbc:EndDate /> 
      <cbc:DescriptionCode /> 
     </cac:InvoicePeriod>
```

Regex written in ABAP:

```
      REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX
    '(<!\[CDATA\[([^]]|(\][^]])|(\]\][^>]))*\]\]>)|(<([^?][^><\s]*)(\s[^><]+)?/>)'
      IN exportxml
      WITH '$1'.
```

After using Regex:

```
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode> 
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>PLN</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode> 
      <cac:InvoicePeriod />
```

SimpleTransformation looks like this:

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates" xmlns:ddic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary" xmlns:def="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/defined">
  <tt:root name="ZXT_INVOICE" type="ddic:ZXT_INVOICE"/>
  <tt:template>
    <Invoice
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
>
      <cbc:DueDate tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.DUEDATE"/>
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.INVOICETYPECODE"/>
      <cbc:Note tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.NOTE"/>
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.DOCUMENTCURRENCYCODE"/>
      <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.TAXCURRENCYCODE"/>
      <cbc:AccountingCost tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.ACCOUNTINGCOST"/>
      <cbc:BuyerReference tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.BUYERREFERENCE"/>
      <cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cbc:StartDate tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.INVOICE_PERIOD.STARTDATE"/>
        <cbc:EndDate tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.INVOICE_PERIOD.ENDDATE"/>
        <cbc:DescriptionCode tt:value-ref=".ZXT_INVOICE.INVOICE_PERIOD.DESCRIPTIONCODE"/>
      </cac:InvoicePeriod>
    </Invoice>
  </tt:template>
</tt:transform>
```

Regex removes simple elements, but has a problem with nested elements like `<cac:InvoicePeriod>`. In my program I have many nested elements..
Can you help me modify regex or find another solution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: seems like running the same regex twice will also remove the `InvoicePeriod`?

Comment: already tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: No need of regex, there's a built-in [option](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transformation_options.htm) when you call the Simple Transformation: `CALL TRANSFORMATION ...
OPTIONS initial_components = 'suppress'.`

Comment: Regex is not a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) for HTML or XML processing. Use @SandraRossi's hint or use an XSLT transformation to achieve what you want (Sandra's solution is much simpler though).

Comment: @Philipp it's not it

Comment: @SandraRossi I tried it but I think nothing happend.. Is it possible that I'm using it wrong? 


  `CALL TRANSFORMATION zx_generate_xml`
   `SOURCE zxt_invoice = invoice`
    `OPTIONS INITIAL_COMPONENTS = 'suppress'`
    `RESULT XML exportxml.   " string / xstring (tried both versions)`

Comment: @Jagger I've never tried anything with xslt, can u link me something?

Comment: @TyRRRax Just copy [Dimitre Novatchev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt). Then use the transformation he provided in `STRANS` transaction. Then you can call this transformation exactly like simple transformation with `CALL TRANSFORMATION`. Just refer to the ABAP documentaiton for this command.

Comment: Hmm you're right, it's not sufficient because the option operates only on the intermediate transformation of the data object to the SAP format ASXML (the XML input of the transformation), and your Simple Transformation always generates the mentioned elements. Please forget this option. Another solution is to change the code of the transformation to not generate the element if it's empty.

Comment: @Jagger Thanks a lot! I read some comments at post that u send me and found similar case.

Answer (score 1):

Your ABAP regex literal :

```
(<!\[CDATA\[([^]]|(\][^]])|(\]\][^>]))*\]\]>)|(<([^?][^><\s]*)(\s[^><]+)?/>)
```

could be corrected and simplified this way :

```
(<!\[CDATA\[(?!\]\]>).*\]\]>)|<[^?!](?:(?!>|\/>).)*\/>
```

NB: `(?!xyz).` is a Negated preview condition, it means any character (`.`) provided that it's not a `x` followed with `yz`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove empty xml elements recursively with XSLT
Solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[string()]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ref links:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776276/remove-empty-xml-elements-recursively-with-xslt)

For me works perfectly. Thanks for help.