# Remove empty tags from generated XML after XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT to transform input XML to output XML. My requirement is I need to remove all empty tags from my output XML during XSLT transformation from input.

I tried the instructions given here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt
```

But probably this talks about the scenario where we are only writing an XSLT for removing the empty tags from an XML. In my case, I will have to eliminate the empty tags while transforming from input XML to output XML (In the same XSLT used for transformation). Can you please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: It is not clear what you consider an `empty tag` in the result of an XSLT transformation, the result is first of all a tree of nodes that might be serialized, if you want to remove empty nodes then define exactly what that is (element node with no child nodes and no attributes or element node with nothing but white space content or?). If you want to really remove empty nodes from the output then chain two transformations where the output of the first is the input of the second. In the world of XSLT 3 there is also no `xsl:where-populated` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#where-populated.

Comment: Please show specimen input and required output, and your best attempt so far. This helps us to understand where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 it might suffice to use `xsl:where-populated` as a "wrapper" for the identity transformation in the match for elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="foo"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```