# XSLT remove xml attributes and empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml as below

I want to transform it to XML using xslt and want to remove empty nodes and one with attribute as below.

```
<ROOT>
<a>this is a </a>
<b />
<c> this is c</c>
<d></d>
<e CSK:nil=“true” xmlIns:xsi=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSxhema-instance” />
<ROOT>
```

And I want to transform it as below with xslt

```
<ROOT>
<a>this is a </a>
<c> this is c</c>
<ROOT>
```

Remove empty nodes or one with attributes  and empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing empty tags from XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt)

Comment: It does partially . It removes <b>, <d> but not <e> as it has attributes

Comment: Instead of csk:nil it is xsi:nil

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!-- Remove nodes with attributes.  -->
<xsl:template match="*[boolean(@*)]"/>

<!-- Remove nodes that are empty or have only spaces. -->
<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(.) = '']"/>

<!-- Keep everything else.  -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```